# Can one grab instantiated objects that were not assigned to a variable?

Tags: python, class, variables, object

Can you grab instantiated objects that were not assigned to a variable?
e.g.:

```
import time
time.time()
```

How can I grab my already instantiated object to call a method for it.
Maybe I can get a list of all instantiated time-objects and then reassign them through a returned id of some sort?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

In the interactive interpreter the last computed value is saved as `_`

```
>>> import time
>>> time.time()
1336296696.824
>>> _
1336296696.824
```

Comment: Cool, I didn't know that. But suppose the last computed value was already something else, is there still a way to save it? Or is it immediately garbage collected?

Comment: Yes, only the last one is saved. Other objects that aren't referenced are garbage collected. That's the base principle of Python's memory management.

Comment: @Bentley4 to save the last computed value, just reference it to a varable, `b=_`

Comment: This only works in the interactive interpreter by the way. So the object *is* still referenced.

Comment: @ThiefMaster Ahh yes that is what i meant, changed it to say 'interactive' in case anybody gets mixed up.

Answer (score 5):

Objects with no references simply don't exist. Python memory management works by reference counting. As soon as an object has no references left, it is destroyed.

Answer (score 3):

This smells like a bad attempt to optimize what doesn't need to be optimized.

Let the GC deal with such an object - it's likely to be deleted immediatels as its reference count is zero right after it has been created.

This also means there is no way to access an unreferenced object.

Comment: I can't think of a good use of it either. But still I wanted to know what python does with that object. Was that such a bad question?

As far as I know every object has a unique id, it could have been possible python had a function that listed all newly created objects since the start of the python session with their id. And there could have been another function that allowed an object to be returned by typing its id. You could then reassign it to a variable.

Answer (score 1):

Assuming you're talking about the REPL, [IPython](http://ipython.org/) (which I highly recommend) allows you to access the result of any past computation.  e.g.:

```
In [1]: 2 * 2 * 2
Out[1]: 8

In [2]: _ * 2
Out[2]: 16

In [3]: _ * 3
Out[3]: 48

In [4]: _1
Out[4]: 8

In [5]: _2
Out[5]: 16

In [6]:
```